# What are different ways to run the client application to verify the response without having server?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, client-server, googletest

I have a CPP client application. As part of client application, I will send a message in encrypt format to http server which will available as part of another server application.

Currently, server application is not yet implemented. But I want to test the client application by running it and I want to verify the response.

What are different ways to run the client application to verify the response without having server? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It very much depends on your code, but in general it's a good idea to follow idea of unit testing. It's a bit late for starting TDD (though it's never too late, you can TDD even old code), but you should separate business logic from the transport layer. Then you can mock the server (i.e. specify clearly what is sent and received from that interface) and test business logic with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Create a small server in local that returns the value who received it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are verifying the response from the server it sounds more like you are unit testing the server instead of the client. Or like an end-to-end test.

If you do want to unit test your client application and you have a separate class that handles the communication, you can mock this communication class and return a hard-coded response. Use this to test if your client handles this response correctly.

If this is not possible you can run a mock HTTP server, as @yumetodo suggests, in a separate process or thread. [httpmockserver](https://github.com/seznam/httpmockserver) seems to provide such a server.